# Delete the first character of array elements in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, substr

I would like to remove the first character from a the elements of an array in a Perl script.

I have this line of script:

```
@dash = split /\s+/, $dash;
```

The variable "dash" is read from a particular row of my file: Example

```
21 A10 A11 A12 A13 ..
```

Then I have tried to push these values to my hash called "flowers"

```
for $i (1..$#dash) {
    push(@flowers, $line[$i]);
}
```

This seems to work for what I need in my subsequent lines of script but I have found out that `$dash` contains unwanted character in front of each values:

```
A10 A11 A12 A13 ..
```

instead of

```
10 11 12 13 .....
```

but I wanted `@flowers` to contain:

```
10 11 12 13 ....
```

How can I delete the first character *Before* I pushed it to my hash (@flowers)

```
chop(@flowers);
```

could have worked but it only chops out the last character. When I tried to use

```
substr($dash, 0, 2)
```

It does produce `10`, but all the rest of the values `A11 A12 A13` is no longer in my `@flowers`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just change the regex in the split?

```
split /\s+\D?/, $dash;
```

Adding them to @flowers this way if you want:

```
push( @flowers, split(/\s+\D?/, $dash) );
```

Answer (score 3):

This will operate on each element of the `@dash` array :

```
@dash = split /\s+/, $dash;
shift @dash;
@dash = map { substr($_, 1) } @dash;
```

Your `substr($dash, 0, 2)` was operating on the line as one string, not each element of it.

And, unless you need the index for some other operation :

```
push @flowers, @dash
```

That will push all elements of `@dash` onto `@flowers`. Which looks like what you're doing.

Comment: @ikegami fixed, I think, I'm not sure what's being described here exactly. Is 21 a line number? Is it always going to be A or A-Z?

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of loop, since you want to do something to each element of `@dash` other than the first. `map` is convenient here.

```
my @flowers = map substr($dash[$_], 1), 1..$#dash;
```

which is the short way of writing

```
my @flowers;
for (1..$#dash) {
   push @flowers, substr($dash[$_], 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you just pull out all the digit sequences from `$dash`, like this:

```
my $dash = '21 A10 A11 A12 A13 .. ';

my @flowers = $dash =~ /\d+/g;
shift @flowers;

print "@flowers";
```

**output**

```
10 11 12 13
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dash = "21 A10 A11 A12 A13"; #test data
my @dash = split /\s+/, $dash; #split into @dash array
shift @dash; #delete first array value
$_ = substr($_,1) for @dash; #for each item in array, remove the first character
print "@dash\n"; #prints: 10 11 12 13
```